# Find duplicates for several columns exclusive ID-column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, duplicates

i've found a lot of answers on how to find duplicates including the PK-column or without focus on it as this:

If you have a table called T1, and the columns are c1, c2 and c3 then this query would show you the duplicate values.

```
SELECT C1, C2, C3, count(*)as DupCount
 from T1
 GROUP BY C1, C2, C3
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

But a more common requirement would be to get the ID of the all duplicates that have equal c1,c2,c3 values.

So i need following what doesn't work because the id must be aggregated:

```
SELECT ID
 from T1
 GROUP BY C1, C2, C3
 HAVING COUNT(*) <> 1
```

(The ID of all duplicates must be different but the columns must be equal)

**Edit**:

Thank you all. I'm always suprised how fast people give excellent answers on Stackoverflow!

Comment: can you provide some sample data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a lot of versions suggested here but I think I came up with a new one.

```
select *
from @T as T1
where exists (select *
              from @T as T2
              where
                T1.ID <> T2.ID and
                T1.C1 = T2.C1 and
                T1.C2 = T2.C2 and
                T1.C3 = T2.C3)
```

Comment: Your approach needs only 11 seconds as against the recursive cte's that need 25 seconds.

Comment: @Tim - They aren't recursive CTEs. They are CTEs using windowed aggregate functions. @Mikael +1 Checking for existence is all that is needed here.

Answer (score 3):

```
;WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT ID,
                C1,
                C2,
                C3,
                COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY C1, C2, C3) AS Cnt
         FROM   T1)
SELECT ID,
       C1,
       C2,
       C3
FROM   CTE
WHERE  Cnt > 1
```

Comment: This answer presumes sql server >= 2005 ?

Comment: @Nathan - Yep. It's 2011 now if the OP needs a 2000 compatible solution they should state it in the question!

Comment: @Martin certainly, but did I miss sqlserver in the question, or can that be assumed since this is SO. :)

Comment: Thank you very much, only 25 seconds. I canceled my first approach after 45 minutes ;)

Answer (score 3):

To get all the rows that are duplicates:

Use this:

```
WITH Dups AS
(
    SELECT *, 
           COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY C1, C2, C3) AS CNT
      FROM T1  
)
SELECT * 
  FROM Dups
 WHERE CNT > 1
```

and to unique row (i.e. retain one row and filter the other duplicate rows) use this:

```
WITH NoDups AS
(
    SELECT *, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY C1, C2, C3 ORDER BY ID) AS RN
      FROM T1  
)
SELECT * 
  FROM NoDups
WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming at least SQL 2005 for the CTE:

```
;with cteDuplicates as (
    select c1, c2, c3
        from t1
        group by c1, c2, c3
        having count(*) > 1
)
select id
    from t1
        inner join cteDuplicates d
            on t1.c1 = d.c1
                and t1.c2 = d.c2
                and t1.c3 = d.c3
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't totally understand your problem, but here is a shot at a different style of solution:

```
select id
from t1 a
join t1 b on a.c1 = b.c2
join t1 c on b.c2 = c.c3
where a.id <> b.id and b.id <> c.id and a.id <> c.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the C1, C2, C3 combination for duplicates into a temp table and then join it to get the IDs.

```
select C1, C2, C3
into #duplicates
from T1
group by C1, C2, C3
having count(*) > 1

select ID
from T1 t
inner join #duplicates d
    on  t.C1 = d.C1
    and t.C2 = d.C2
    and t.C3 = d.C3
```